What's the name of this historical famous movie?
It's a famous historical Greek movie and characters names are sound like Agelaus, Aenesidemos. I guess it made at 90s or early 00s.
Plot: A tribe chief is lost at sea in a storm. His young son and his wife go to a city (called Isaka?!).  People looking for the chief but can't find him.
A bad guy who tries to win the leadership  of the city wants to marry the chief's wife but the young son still think his father is alive and tries to find his father in nearby islands. After some adventures he find his father and they both come back to the city and that bad guy can't achieve desired goals. 

Was the film in Greek? Or English? Was it a Greek, American, or other production? Chances are this movie was a version of Homer's Odyssey

YEAH! You found it. Couple hours googling don't have any result but you found it less than 5 min. Thanks bro. Please add it as an answer to pick it as best answer!

Please mark the correct answer as accepted ... the check mark next to it.

@HorusKol Why you don't add an answer? You found the movie name first and unfortunately I can't choose your answer as the best one bcz it's only a comment.

I didnt find the movie - I recognised the Greek epic it was based on. Happy for someone else to credit for the actual ID

Maybe this version of "The Odyssey" from 1997?



[

Some explanation as to why you think this suggestion is correct wouldn't go amiss here. For one, Odysseus' home is in Ithaca, heavily suggesting it is at least a rendition of the Odyssey.
